# flutter installations on VS code: how to run the flutter code on emmulator

Tags: flutter

I have installed flutter and it is working fine on chrome but when I am trying to run on emmulator I am getting this text "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'..."
please tell me how to resolve this. On local host I got the output but not on the emmulator

hpw do I resolve the problem

Comment: have you installed android studio, setup adb, setup android emulator and created a emulator

Comment: yes, I have installed android studio. I also got the phone screen on the laptop.after that when I did "run without debugging" on chrome I got the output but when I tried doing by changing from chrome to emulator in the screen I am unable to see the output in the Debug console it's giving the error as "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'..."

Comment: First of all that not the error its just log to tell current process status but it takes long sometimes please wait for it to complete then if you really get any error then the process will be stopped

Comment: phone screen pops up on my laptop but I guess the emulator is not synchronizing with VS code.As you say when I get "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'..." in the console I should wait for some time

Comment: Yeah coz android building is a long task with many grade scripts behind the scenes if you even get stuck with that then try on real Android device and connect it with through and try on it